# hilbert matrix in octave to given Number

Tags: matrix, octave

I'm supposed to create a Hilbert-Matrix H by the following input:

Hilbert(n=4):

[image: HilbertMatrix]

This is what I tried. It's rubbish. Could anybody help me out here?

```
function H = hilbertmatrix(n)
    i=1; 
for i=1:n;`


H=[(1:(1/i+1)) (1:(1/i+1);
   (1:(1/i+1)) (1:(1/i+1)];                          `

end
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. So I will answer my own question.

```
`function [H,h] = hilbertmatrix(n)

 J = 1:n;
 J = J(ones(n,1),:);
 I = J';
 E = single(ones(n,n));
 H = E./(I+J-1);         %H will give the hilbertmatrix in accordance to the
                         %code above
 h = hilb(n);            %h is for reference.
end
endfunction`
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [hilb](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Famous-Matrices.html#XREFhilb)

```
hilb(4)
ans =

   1.00000   0.50000   0.33333   0.25000
   0.50000   0.33333   0.25000   0.20000
   0.33333   0.25000   0.20000   0.16667
   0.25000   0.20000   0.16667   0.14286
```

Comment: Ok, so that would be the answer to n=4. But I'm supposed to create an m-file that allows me to input any integer. For example I type `hilbertmatrix(6)`and octave would take my m-file and create that matrix. I shold mention that I'm not supposed to make use of the implemented fuctions.

Comment: Then I would kindly advise to go through your lecture thoroughly, and/or practice a [tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial), especially the part about vectors and matrices. Because your present code shows a too shallow understanding of the octave syntax to achieve this homework correctly.

Comment: I know and it's not my intention to understand it. I have loads of respect for people who are capable of understanding stuff like that - I'm not that person, nor will I ever be. I'm forced to pass that one test, though. My job is a completely different field... that's why I simply ask for the solution. Is that OK?